# Дружественные функции - зачем они нужны?

Tags: c++, функции

Только что с ними разобрался, но не вижу их применения. Где их применяют?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дружественные функции чаще всего не нужны и даже вредны, т. к. они разрушают инкапсуляцию. Однако иногда всё-таки без нарушения инкапсуляции трудно.

Классический пример — бинарный оператор. Хорошим тоном является определение бинарного оператора как внешней статической функции. Для того, чтобы эффективнее вычислять значение, оператору может понадобиться доступ «внутрь» класса, так что его приходится объявлять `friend`'ом.

Пример:

```
class YetAnotherString
{
    char* m_data;
    int m_length, m_capacity;

    YetAnotherString(int length)
    {
        m_length = length;
        PrepareBuffer();
    }

    void PrepareBuffer()
    {
        m_capacity = ((m_length + 31) / 32) * 32 // выровнять на 32 байта
        m_data = new char[m_capacity + 1];
    }

  public:
    YetAnotherString(const char* data)
    {
        m_length = strlen(data);
        PrepareBuffer();
        strcpy(m_data, data);
    }
    int GetLength() { return m_length; }
    char* GetCStr() { return m_data; }
    // тут ещё оператор присваивания, копирующий конструктор
    // и деструктор
    friend operator + (char* raw, const YetAnotherString& string);
};

YetAnotherString operator + (char* raw, const YetAnotherString& string)
{
    int lhsLength = strlen(raw);
    int rhsLength = string.GetLength();
    // мы хотим избежать ненужного копирования в конструкторе YetAnotherString
    // поэтому пользуемся приватным конструктором
    // без friend-декларации это бы не скомпилировалось
    YetAnotherString result(lhsLength + rhsLength);
    strcpy(result.m_data, raw);
    strcpy(result.m_data + lhsLength, string.GetCStr());
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @VladD ага, точно. Еще нашел вариант перегрузки (<<) и (>>) операторов с такой функцией. Насчет подрыва инкапсуляции весьма согласен.

Comment: Я так понимаю, еще профит от того, что мы можем убрать зависимость от порядка аргументов (в случае определения бинарного оператора как ДФ). obj + 1, 1 + obj.

Comment: @smackmychi: Ну, тут профит приходит от объявления оператора внешней функцией. А для внешней функции понадобилась `friend`-декларация.

Comment: Как вариант, я часто реализую управляющий потоком класс, который при своем создании создает поток (функцию-друга) и передает ей себя. А при удалении класса интерраптит поток, потом ждет, пока он умрет, и после этого выходит из деструктора. Если поток умирает по какой-то еще причине, выставляет в классе соответствующее поле.   
В итоге есть класс, управляющий жизнью потока (пока класс жив + правильное поле - поток жив, класс мертв - поток гарантированно мертв). Это удобно. И один из вариантов кошерной реализации - если функция потока - друг управляющего ею класса.